# How to mock up a firebase.database.ServerValue.increment() function using Jest

Tags: javascript, firebase, jestjs

I've a component updating variables of a user:

```js
const sendPost = () => {

   let userProps = {

       name: userName,
       profilePic: userPhoto,
       numPosts: firebase.database.ServerValue.increment(1)

   }

   firebase.database().ref(`user/${uid}`).update(userProps);

}
```

To test the component I want to create a mock up for `firebase.database.ServerValue.increment()` using Jest.

My test so far:

```js
import React                                  from 'react';
import { render, fireEvent, screen, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';
import { BrowserRouter }                      from 'react-router-dom';
import NewPost                                from '../Components/NewPost';
import firebase                               from '../Functions/Firebase';
import UserContext                            from '../Functions/UserContext';
import * as GetLevel                          from '../Functions/GetLevelAndPointsToNextLevel';

test('NewPost -> Users with level < 15 (premium) are allowed to publish new posts', async () => {
   
    jest.spyOn(GetLevel, 'default').mockImplementation(() => [14, '_', '_']);
    
    const userInfo = { 
        
        account: 'premium'
        
    };
    
    const snapshot = { val: () => userInfo };    
    
    jest.spyOn(firebase, 'database').mockImplementation(() => ({
        
        ref:         jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
        on:          jest.fn((event, callback) => callback(snapshot)),
        off:         jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
        once:        jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({val: () => 0})),
        push:        jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
        update:      jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
        transaction: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
        ServerValue: jest.fn().mockReturnThis()
        
    }));
    
    render(
        <UserContext.Provider value = {{user: true}}>
            <NewPost/>
        </UserContext.Provider>
    );
    
    fireEvent.change(screen.getByPlaceholderText('Título...'),  { target: { value: 'Some random title' } });
    fireEvent.change(screen.getByPlaceholderText('Mensaje...'), { target: { value: 'Some random message' } });
    
    fireEvent.click(document.querySelector('button.bottom'));
    
    await waitFor(() => expect(document.querySelector('.Alert .Message').textContent).toBe('¡Mensaje enviado!'));
    
});
```

The problem is that, after running the test, I'm getting the following:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'increment' of undefined

The component works well E2E. So it's a problem of mocking up the function correctly.

How can I mock up `firebase.database.ServerValue.increment()` properly?

Comment: Can you share more about your component implementation & its test as well? So we could provide you a proper fix then.

Comment: The function that I want to mock up is here https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/database/ServerValue#increment(kotlin.Long). I don't care about the value to return in the mock up. I'm not sure if sharing more information about my implementation would be helpful. Could you specify, please?

Comment: I don't mind which package you used. I just care about the way you import things & mock it, where you currently place your code as well. That's why I asked to see entire your component & test files

Comment: Got it. I just edited the question, I hope it helps.

Comment: Hold on. The `database` is supposed to be a function based on your mock. Are you forgetting calling it? `firebase.database.ServerValue` (should be `firebase.database().ServerValue `)

Comment: Per [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database):

1. firebase.database() can be called with no arguments to access the default app's Database service .
2. firebase.database is also a namespace that can be used to access global constants and methods associated with the Database service.

In this case, I should call `firebase.database.ServerValue` without brackets. Otherwise, I will get an error on E2E test. 

The problem may be that I'm mixing both options when I'm trying to set a `spyOn` method for `firebase.database`.

Comment: Maybe I should create a separate mock up function for `firebase.database.ServerValue` (without brackets). I'm confused...

Comment: Or you could also move its namespace as new function in a different module then mock that module. I don't think it's easy to mock one property returning 2 different things :)

Comment: Thanks @tmhao2005. I think you got the solution. Could you explain me with code how to create a new module with the namespace as a function and mock that module?